# pushing array to array in ruby have a wrong result

Tags: ruby

I have problem when pushing array to array,
the result is not as I expected.

I run this code below :

```
 @arr = ["e", "s", "l", "e"]

    def permutations(array, i=0)
      combined_array = Array.new
      (i..array.size-1).each do |j|
        array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
        puts "ARRAY : #{array}"
        combined_array << array.to_a
      end
      return combined_array
    end

permutations(@arr)
```

I got the output :

```
ARRAY : ["e", "s", "l", "e"]
ARRAY : ["s", "e", "l", "e"]
ARRAY : ["l", "e", "s", "e"]
ARRAY : ["e", "e", "s", "l"]
=> [["e", "e", "s", "l"], ["e", "e", "s", "l"], ["e", "e", "s", "l"], ["e", "e", "s", "l"]]
```

Result expected :

```
ARRAY : ["e", "s", "l", "e"]
ARRAY : ["s", "e", "l", "e"]
ARRAY : ["l", "e", "s", "e"]
ARRAY : ["e", "e", "s", "l"]
=> [["e", "s", "l", "e"], ["s", "e", "l", "e"], ["l", "e", "s", "e"], ["e", "e", "s", "l"]]
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you know there is a predefined method `permutation` in Array class?

Comment: You don't have to write separate method for this. You simply write `p arr.permutation.map{|s|s}` that would do the job for you.

Comment: Hello @Rajagopalan, i knew that method, but for the big array, it will out of memory

Comment: Hi I have updated answer, you may have a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-to_a), `#to_a` called on an `Array` returns `self` (the array itself, not a copy).

You are adding the same array to `combined_array` multiple times.

Change the `.to_a` to `.dup` and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think @GolfWolf has solved your problem.

But you don't have to write such a function to solve your problem in Ruby, Ruby has `permutation` method which you can use it.

```
p arr.permutation.to_a
```

If you want to get first 4 element then you can do this,

```
p arr.permutation.take(4)
```

Comment: You'd probably be better off saying `arr.permutation.to_a` instead of the `map{|s|s}`. And the second one doesn't need any arrayification, just `arr.permutation.take(4)` would be sufficient.

Comment: @muistooshort Ah Okay! Thank you, updated the answer!